# How to run function, when the user finished typing? (C#)

Tags: c#, winforms, keyboard

I have a text field in which the user inserts or typing text for further translation into another language. I need to run the function after the user finished typing - how to determine it?

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "finished typing"? When the text of the text box did not change for a certain amount of time? When the text box loses focus? When the user presses enter?

Comment: @Sweeper, by "finished typing" I mean the following: the text inside the text field does not change for some time, and then the function is called.

Answer (score 0):

**!!! Note the order of settings for the timer**

```
// Create a System.Timers.Timer
System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();

// On KeyUp, start the countdown
private void richTextBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
    aTimer.Interval = 1000; // time in ms (1 sec)
    aTimer.AutoReset = false; // "false" - calls the event once, "true" - repeatedly

    aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimeout; // event binding
    aTimer.Enabled = true; // timer run
}

private void OnTimeout(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e) {
    if (InvokeRequired) Invoke(new Action(() => DoneTyping() ));
}

// User is "finished typing", do something
private void DoneTyping() {
    // do something
}
```